# How do I get bc to start decimal fractions with a leading zero

Tags: bc

How do I get `bc` to start decimal fractions with a leading zero?

```
$ bc <<< 'scale=4; 1/3'
  .3333
```

I want 0.3333.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402181/how-do-i-get-bc1-to-print-the-leading-zero

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bc` natively does not support adding zero.

Workaround is:

```bash
echo 'scale=4; 1/3' | bc -l | awk '{printf "%.4f\n", $0}'
0.3333
```

- `\n`  – terminate the output with a newline.
- `%f`  – floating point
- `%.4f` – the number of digits to show. 
  This specifies 4 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Unless you need BigNum features of `bc`, just `echo 1 3 4 | awk '{ printf ("%.*f\n", $3, $1 / $2); }'`. But gawk has BigNum compiled in anyway (on most distros).

Comment: If the question-asker didn’t need the ``-l`` (math library) option to ``bc``,  your answer doesn’t need it either.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `bc` is written in such a way that you cannot. This statement also applies to its neighbor `dc`. People, as a solution, usually suggest using some text-processing tool to change `bc` output, or use completely different tool like `perl` or `python` which has different syntax, but to me they seems to be too heavy for such simple task.

From your other questions it looks that you are `zsh` user so I would suggest `zcalc`, which has very similar syntax for basic operations like `bc`:

```
$ zcalc -e '1/3'
0.333333
```

First you need to load this function (e.g. inside `.zshrc`) and probably you may want to always treat all numbers as a floating point with `-f` option:

```
autoload -U zcalc
alias zcalc='zcalc -f'
```

As a bonus, you can define special prompt for the calculator with `ZCALCPROMPT` parameter, for details look at `man zshcontrib`.

Comment: One day, when I get mad at this enough, I'll fix Linux pipelines to be executable fully in-process, sans execs, forks, and context switches, ending this stupid builtin/external dichotomy once and for all.

Comment: @PSkocik:  I’m curious what your plan is.    Do you plan to make every program in the world internal to the shell?

Answer (score 2):

`bc` can be persuaded to use a leading zero:

```
for div in 10 1000; do 
  echo "scale=3;v=158/$div; if(v > -1 && v < 1) print 0,v,\"\n\" else print v, \"\n\"" | bc
done
```

Comment: You check for `v > -1`, but that doesn't work for negative numbers as you insert the `0` before the sign (and get something like `0-.158` instead of `-0.158`).

Comment: Also, if the result is zero, your routine will print ``00``.

Comment: Yes - I wrote that code fragment for a specific use-case after discovering the issue myself. Nothing like a problem to spur one to hack a solution. Following your comments I've written a small function that seems to address those and others. I'll post it as a new answer since it is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `awk` if you have `printf`
(either builtin to the shell, or as a separate program).

If you specifically want four digits to the right of the decimal point,

```
$ printf '%.4f\n'            "$(bc <<< 'scale=4; 1/7')"
0.1428
```

If you want to make it scriptable,

```
$ ndigits=4
$ printf '%.*f\n' "$ndigits" "$(bc <<< "scale=$ndigits; 1/7")"
0.1428
```

If you want to suppress trailing zeroes, use `%g` instead of `%f`.

```
$ printf '%.4g\n'   "$(bc <<< 'scale=4; 1/3')" \
                    "$(bc <<< 'scale=4; 1/4')" \
                    "$(bc <<< 'scale=4; 1/7')" \
                    "$(bc <<< 'scale=4; 1/8')"
0.3333
0.25
0.1428
0.125
```

But this works the way you want only if the value is between −1 and 1:

```
$ printf '%.4g\n'   "$(bc <<< 'scale=4; 1/7')" \
                    "$(bc <<< 'scale=4; 10/7')" \
                    "$(bc <<< 'scale=4; 100/7')" \
                    "$(bc <<< 'scale=4; 1000/7')"
0.1428
1.429
14.29
142.9
```

because the `4` here is interpreted as the *total* number of digits,
not the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: Note that with several `printf` implementations, that won't work if the locale decimal radix character is the *comma* instead of *period* as `printf` honours is but `bc` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is a belt-and-braces solution that addresses the failures using my previous answer. This small function somewhat intelligently figures out when and where to stick the leading 0 and negative sign and uses the `backspace` control-code to move backwards in the printed value. It won't work in Posix `-s|--standard` mode (or if printed on a Teletype!):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bc
# this is lz.bc
define lz(d) {
  if (ibase != 10 || obase != 10) {
    print "(io)base must be decimal (10)\n"
    return -1
  }
  n=0; b=0; a=0
  if (d<0) n=1 # negative
  if (d>-1 && d<0) b=1 # below
  if (d>0 && d<1) a=1  # above
  print " ", d
  for (i=length(d)+1; i>=0; i--) {
    print "\b"
    if(i==0 && (b || a)) print "0\b\b"
  }
  if(n) print "-"
  print "\n"
  return 0
}

v[0]=-.234
v[1]=.234
v[2]=-2.345
v[3]=2.345
v[4]=-123.4567
v[5]=123.456
for(x=0;x<6;x++) {
  print v[x], " ... "
  r=lz(v[x])
}
obase=16
r=lz(v[5])
quit
```

which when called displays:

```
$ bc lz.bc 
bc 1.07.1
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006, 2008, 2012-2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
-.234 ... -0.234
.234 ... 0.234
-2.345 ...  -2.345
2.345 ...  2.345
-123.4567 ...  -123.4567
123.456 ...  123.456
(io)base must be decimal (10)
```